# SignalR Scaleout on Azure RedisCache - Connection issues

Tags: c#, azure, redis, signalr

Based on information here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis , I've stood up an [Azure Redis Cache](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/).  I've been scaling out SignalR over Azure ServiceBus up until this point, but frankly it drops a lot of messages and I'd like to investigate the other options.  I'm trying to just do a little bit of a discovery run with my new Azure Redis Cache instance, but my app will no longer run with the single line configuration change.

**EDIT** - 
I should add that I'm using the SignalR 2.2.0 libraries.

Old Code:

```
var sbConnString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(sbConnString, ApplicationGlobals.APPLICATION_NAME);
```

New Code:

```
var redisConnString = "MYAPP.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password=PRIMARY_ACCESS_KEY";
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(redisConnString, "MYAPP"));
```

New Code Variant 2:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis("MYAPP.redis.cache.windows.net", 6380, "PRIMARY_ACCESS_KEY", "MYAPP"));
```

I've tried all permutations of SSL/Non-SSL, connection string constructor vs parameter contructor etc., but I've yet to run the WebApp successfully with the Redis scaleout configuration.  What am I doing wrong?

[image: Azure Redis Cache]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I regenerated the Access Keys and everything started working.  It was helpful to create a little console app based on StackExchange.Redis to test the connection outside of signalR.

I found this ScottGu's [post about RedisCache](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/azure-redis-cache-disaster-recovery-to-azure-tagging-support-elastic-scale-for-sqldb-docdb) helpful.